# Lambda - Querying DynamoDB through Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

1. I have a table called Customers with attributes CustId(partition Key), Fname, Lname, Dob.
2. I created a secondary index called LastNameIndex on Lname with the following params:

```yaml
{
    TableName: 'Customers'
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
          AttributeName: 'Lname',
          AttributeType: 'S'
        }
    ],
    GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates: [

        {
            Create: {
                IndexName: "LastNameIndex",
                KeySchema: [
                    {AttributeName: "Lname", KeyType: "HASH"}
                    
                ],
                Projection: {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                },
                ProvisionedThroughput: {                                
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,"WriteCapacityUnits": 1
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Lambda function (snippet) - I want to get all records with Lname=Connors

```js
params = {         
    TableName: "Customers",
    IndexName: "LastNameIndex",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#FN": "Fname", 
        "#LN": "Lname",
        "#DB": "Dob",
        
    }, 
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":a": {
            S: "Connors"
        } 
    }, 
    KeyConditionExpression: "Lname = :a",
    ProjectionExpression: "#FN, #LN, #DB"
};
```

4. Running the query

```js
ddb.query(params).promise().then(

    function(data) {
        console.log("Customer:" + data.Item)
        return data.Item;
    },
    function() {
        console.log("No records found...")
    }
);
```

5. I have a record with Lname = Connors.
6. But the query does not return me any records - any idea what's wrong with the params?

Comment: Could you try using  

` ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":a":  "Connors"
    },` ?

Comment: ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":a": "Connors" },`  did not return any records

Comment: Console logging the returned `data` would help. Also, consider using the DocumentClient going forward as it has better support for native JS type inference and you can replace constructs such as `":a": {S: "Connors"}` with `":a": "Connors"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` operation returns multiple items not a single item like `getItem` operation. so I think returning **data.Items** instead of data.Item should work just fine.

```
ddb.query(params).promise().then(

    function(data) {
        console.log("Customer:" + data.Items)
        return data.Items;
    },
    function() {
        console.log("No records found...")
    }
);
```

Comment: I have accepted Ahmad Nabil's answer. I was thinking my params were wrong. However my params were correct, the way I was processing the results was wrong. Because it is a query it returns a array of records. I corrected my code as follows: ***ddb.query(params).promise().then(
   function(data) {
    console.log("Customer:" + data);
    data.Items.forEach(function(customer) {
      customer.Fname + ": " + customer.Lname +  customer.Dob + "\n";
    });
    return data.Items;
   },
   function() {
    console.log("No records found...")
   }
  );***

Comment: As jarmod mentioned I would also recommend using documentClient instead because it's easier to work with. Also consider using aws sdk v3 for better performance than sdk v2.